# Change date from bash script

Tags: bash

for some testing i need a bash script which can change the time of the server. Right now when i check the current date with the "date" command it shows me the date like following:
Wed 21 Aug 2019 09:27:48 PM CEST

My bash script looks like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
DatePlus1Hour=`date --date="now 1 hour"`
/usr/bin/date --set=$DatePlus1Hour
#echo $DatePlus1Hour
exit
```

But no matter how i change the syntax i always get this error:
/usr/bin/date: extra operand ‘Aug’

When i echo the variable $DatePlus1Hour instead it shows me the correct date plus 1 hour added. However i don't want to display the modified date, i want it to change the server time.

Thanks in advance for any possible help!
Markus

Comment: @WildWilly : Since you are using `bash`, you have to quote the variable, because it contains spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues in your script to fix:

Change:

```sh
DatePlus1Hour=`date --date="now 1 hour"`
```

to:

```sh
DatePlus1Hour="$(date --utc --iso=ns --date="now 1 hour")"
```

to have your `DatePlus1Hour` contain a date format into the **iso-8601** format that is compatible with the `--set` argument of the `date` command.

Next, change:

```sh
/usr/bin/date --set=$DatePlus1Hour
```

to:

```sh
sudo /usr/bin/date --utc --set="$DatePlus1Hour"
```

to have the variable quoted and avoid splitting expanding your date string into space delimited fields.

You also need to use `sudo` because altering the system's date is a privileged action that is not authorized to normal users.

**Finally and most importantly:**

Storing the date with computed offset into a variable and setting the date from the variable **is not an atomic operation**. It will certainly introduce loss of a few nanoseconds in-between the two shell statements.

Fortunately, it is possible to offset the system time directly with an atomic operation:

```sh
sudo date --set="now +1 hour"
```